# how to open report wizard ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

How to get to this wizard after my report has been created? When I create a new report I can find this thing, but not when I already have a report.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you can't once your report is made. The wizard is a first pass through only. I ended up writing my own report wizard because I didn't like the built-in one and wanted editability based on a config file, but that was a huge undertaking.

Comment: If this is the case, can I get your wizard plesae?

Comment: It was very proprietary unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great solution, but might be better than starting over with the wizard. You can save the .rdl for the report to your machine and then look into modifying the rdl manually. I can't provide any real guidance here except that I was wondering how to do the exact thing you asked.

Note the **Tablix** tags as they represent your table(s). It looks like everything could be adjusted by hand here so long as you had a pretty good idea of how you wanted your table to display. I would strongly recommend starting with an rdl where the report already has as many of the elements you need to use. Changing existing values will be much easier than deriving them from scratch.

I know it's not the answer you want. It's not even the answer I want. But...I think this is the only option left aside from deleting the table and recreating via the wizard.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Report Builder you can launch de Wizard from the ribbon chart, tablix and matrix options.

Comment: This is not what was asked. He wants to know how to change an existing table via the wizard.